# Does the function $|x^2-4|/x$ have critical points?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Does the function $|x^2-4|/x$ have critical points?

I tried differentiating and putting the derivative equal to 0.But I'm still a bit confused (as I got no solution).

Comment: Did you treat it as a piecewise function?

Comment: You really need to divide it into the cases $x^2-4 >0$ and $x^2-4 \leq 0$, which actually breaks up the line into three pieces.

Comment: please DRAW A PICTURE  by hand  http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: hmmm, first draw $y= |x^2 - 4|$

Answer (score 1):

0 - undefined, +2 and -2 as the sign of numerator changes

Answer (score 1):

For
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\frac{|x^2-4|}{x}&=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x^2-4}{x}&x\in]-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty[\\ \dfrac{4-x^2}{x}&x\in]-2,2[\end{cases}
\end{align*}
we have
\begin{align*}
f'(x)=&=\begin{cases}\dfrac{x^2+4}{x^2}&x\in]-\infty,-2[\cup]2,\infty[\\ -\dfrac{x^2+4}{x^2}&x\in]-2,2[\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Observe $f'(x)$ is not defined for $x=\pm2$.

Answer (score 1):

A perhaps more brutish way of dealing with this is to write $$\frac{|x^2 - 4|}{x} = \frac{\sqrt{(x^2-4)^2}}{x} $$
then deal with it as normal and achieve the answers +2 and -2.

Answer (score 0):

critical points are points in the domain where either $f'=0$ or $f'$ is undefined.

$f'$ is never zero for your example but it is undefined at $x=0, 2, -2$

$x=0$ does not count as critical because it is not in the domain of $f$ 
but $x=\pm2$ are both critical points ( in fact they are both local extrema )

Answer (score 0):

learn to draw graphs. By hand.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First graph I understood.How did you draw second graph?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, if you get some graph paper, and just fill in dots for $y = |x^2-4|/x$ when $x=0.2, 0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0, 1.2, 1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0, 2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0, 3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8, 4.0,4.2   $ you will understand pretty well. http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph